# lpr: Error - unknown option “V”

Tags: printing

I am getting this error when trying to run the lpr command:

> lpr: Error - unknown option "V".

The full command I am running is:

```
lpr -V -P printer-1 file.txt
```

According to the documentation here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/lpr.1.html there is a -V flag.

If I run the command without the -V flag it prints fine, however I need output so the application I am building knows if the print was successful or not.

I have tried this on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS.

This page http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/lpr.1.php says:

> The "c", "d", "f", "g", "i", "m", "n", "t", **"v"**, and "w" options are not supported by CUPS and will produce a warning message if used.

So, is there a Linux distribution that does not use CUPS and uses another printing system which does have a verbose flag?

Comment: The first refers to the `lprng` package, not `lpr` from cups. Can't you just check the return value?

Comment: @noleti The return value would not tell me if the print was successful though, correct? Just if the command was valid. 
And would lprng be a suitable alternative?

Comment: not sure about the return value, it would be easiest to just try. I can't help with lprng, just wanted to point out why man pages differed